# How to display data using only getters in c++ of tenure of a teacher more than 2

Tags: c++

A class named “Teacher” holds information like teacher code, name, gender, year of joining.
Write a program to create three objects of teacher class and enter some data into it through
setters. Make getters and setters for all employee information. Then ask the user to enter
the current year. Display the names of those employees whose tenure is 2 or more than 2 years
according to the given current year only using getters.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: This is not a question, this description explains nothing but your homework/assignment. Please be specific and make more effort.